# Reduce function syntax in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to know whats wrong with my code. I am trying  to solve system of non-linear equations (initially in wolfram but the command was too long) in Mathematica:

```
Reduce[Pi*(h^2 + 2*R*(R - r))/sqrt (h^2 + (R - r)^2) - 2*x*Pi/3*h*R - 
     x*Pi/3*h*r == 0 && 
   Pi*(h^2 + 2*r*(r - R))/sqrt (h^2 + (R - r)^2) + 2*Pi*r - 
     x*Pi/3*h*R - 2*x*Pi/3*h*r == 0 && 
   Pi*h*(r + R)/sqrt (h^2 + (R - r)^2) - x*Pi/3*R^2 - x*Pi/3*R*r - 
     x*Pi/3*r^2 == 0 && -Pi/3*h*(R^2 + R*r + r^2) + 1 == 0, {R, r, h, 
   x}];
```

Do you know how to retype it and solve these equations? I tried to type it according to documentation, but I evidently made some mistake...

These are the original equations (in LaTeX, I dont know if they will show correctly here:

```
\begin{equation*}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial R} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi(h^2 + 2R(R-r))}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} - 2\lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hR - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hr= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial r} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi(h^2 + 2r(r-R))}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} + 2\pi r - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hR - 2\lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hr= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial h} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi h(r + R)}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}R^2 - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}Rr - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}r^2= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = - \frac{\pi}{3} h (R^2 + Rr + r^2) + 1 = 0
\end{equation*}
```

---

#### edit:

I corrected pi to PI, now it started evaluating so maybe it was the mistake...It just takes a very long time...

Comment: You may use `pi` to mean `π` but Mathematica doesn't, it uses `Pi`. That will probably hinder your successful reduction.

Comment: And square root is `Sqrt[]` not `sqrt()` - capitalize functions, and use square brackets so it'd be `Sqrt[(h^2+(R-r)^2)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to learn at least the basics. Go to Help->Documentation Center and click on the book in the search bar. There is everything explained from the very start.

As already pointed out in the comments, **all** functions and built-in symbols start with a capital letter. Therefore your call should be

```
Reduce[Pi*(h^2 + 2*R*(R - r))/Sqrt[h^2 + (R - r)^2] - 2*x*Pi/3*h*R - 
    x*Pi/3*h*r == 0 && 
  Pi*(h^2 + 2*r*(r - R))/Sqrt[h^2 + (R - r)^2] + 2*Pi*r - 
    x*Pi/3*h*R - 2*x*Pi/3*h*r == 0 && 
  Pi*h*(r + R)/Sqrt[h^2 + (R - r)^2] - x*Pi/3*R^2 - x*Pi/3*R*r - 
    x*Pi/3*r^2 == 0 && -Pi/3*h*(R^2 + R*r + r^2) + 1 == 0, {R, r, h, 
  x}]
```